# How to remove white spaces before each value from array list in the java code below

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, removing-whitespace

```
test_map = new HashMap();
json_test_data = slurper.parseText(test_data.toString());
test_map=json_test_data.row;
code_list = test_map.getAt("code").toString();
```

**Output:**

```
code_list: [
    QU95QE007, IP2H1N001, Q37VS001, Q2908003,
    Q2C94001, 2FZ3001, 94DM002, 193R005,
    2FZ3001,  94DM002,  193R005,  94DM002
]
```

Comment: please elaborate the expected output and actual output. this is not clear enough. also share the inputs.

Comment: `String.replaceAll()` [method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) to replace whitespace from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Since a String is an array of characters. Try to change the first element of the string to an empty char like this "" cause before it was this " "